# Font Awesome Icons Hover effect not working

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Developing a site and using a couple of font awesome icons.  Need to be able to change the color of them when the user hovers over one.

Here is my css to make them change color on hover

```css
.icon:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

**Here is where the icon is created**

```html
<i id="mod_squad" class="x-icon icon x-icon-angle-right" style="text-align: center; color: rgb(25, 25, 25); font-size: 25px;" data-x-icon="&#xf105;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Probably the inline styling is overruling your external css rules. Use a higher specificity, or `!important` if you must.

Comment: I would not recommend to use the !important, as it will create lots of issues later on when you need to change your css again. I recommend that you extract the inline styling out to a class, like .x-icon--default{ text-align: center; color: rgb(25, 25, 25); font-size: 25px;}. Then use a higher specificity on the hover like i.x-icon--default:hover{color:blue;} to achieve the change in color when hovering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that inline CSS styles always take precedence over external CSS styles.

One easy workaround would be to add `!important` after the property you want to override inside your CSS:

```css
.test:hover {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<span class="test" style="color: red;">Lorem Ipsum</span
```

**Important:** This is not the recommended approach however, I would highly suggest you move the inline CSS inside your external CSS styles.

Comment: why not remove the inline styles and use it in head style tag or external 
 css doc? that would be a better approach I guess

Comment: Yes that's why I wrote at the end. Let me emphasize it.

Comment: You got it...can't believe I forgot to try that.  Thanks!